# Git / Jira - Can't checkout out any new branches

Tags: git, jira

So my usual workflow is make an issue/item on my Jira Project Board, then go to my Visual Studio Code editor, then the normal stuff like going to master and pulling down the latest version then I use the following command as an example:

`git fetch && git checkout WOR-item-47`

So I'm suddenly getting this error on git on this project im working on:

`error: pathspec 'WOR-item-47' did not match any file(s) known to git`

and when I use the command `git branch -a` (on the master) to list out all branches it will list out all created branches until `WOR-item-46`, and it will not have `WR-item-47` in the list. So it's nearly like my local is out of sync with what is happening on the Jira board.

This seemed to happen over night so I'm not sure if I actually did something wrong, has anybody else this issue?

Comment: Did creating the jira ticket _automagically_ create a branch on the remote repository before? The way you are asking to create the branch on checkout _ assumes_ there's a branch on a remote with that name.

Comment: Sounds like you have something configured in Jira to create branches for you, and it broke somehow. Without more details of your Jira setup, I doubt anyone could give you more than wild guesses.

Comment: You can run `git ls-remote | grep refs/heads/WOR-item-47` to check if the branch exists in the remote repository. If it prints nothing, the reason could be either that `WOR-item-47` does not exist yet or that your username does not have access to the branch.

Comment: so this is fixed now ... it was a combination of someone else unknowingly changing permissions on all the files on a commit of their own and then me going out of sync with the repo. Thanks for replying, it honestly helped to fix this.